# Magento 2: Disable Welcome Email Using preference

Tags: magento2, customer-account, preference

**How to Disable Customer Welcome Email Only Using preference not with plugin**

Comment: Would it be possible to explain your problem a little more, what you did and what didn't work and why you don't want to use the plugin when it is recommended by Magento instead preference and possible for this method ?

Comment: If you want to use reference, better to create reference for `Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotificationInterface`. But I suggest to use plugin for the interface and use `around` with correct `sortOrder` for prevent to replace your logic by 3rd party extension like DotMailer, etc.

Comment: Hey @PЯINCƎ and Victor Tihonchuk thank you for your reply i have completed my task using below answer.

Comment: Preference is never a good solution, you can use plugin or event observer

Comment: okay thanks @Pyaray Afzel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your preference like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification" type="Vendor\Module\Model\NoEmailNotification" />
</config>
```

and then override the `newAccount` method as follows:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Onepage;

class NoEmailNotification extends \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification
{
      /**
     * Don't send email with new account related information
     *
     * @param CustomerInterface $customer
     * @param string $type
     * @param string $backUrl
     * @param int|null $storeId
     * @param string $sendemailStoreId
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function newAccount(
        CustomerInterface $customer,
        $type = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED,
        $backUrl = '',
        $storeId = null,
        $sendemailStoreId = null
    ): void {
        return;
    }
}
```

Which essentially inverts the original functionality of the method linked here (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/cd826aa2215e19d543a3a606aebde18fa3e40d4e/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/EmailNotification.php#L384)

So the customer no longer receives a welcome email

Comment: Hey @SNAFU thank you so much its working fine

Comment: You're very welcome @Imran :)